# Run setTimeout with changing time values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, settimeout

I have an array of objects containing a field `duration` that specifies the duration that the `Object` should stay visible.

Each `Object` of array has it's own `duration`.

So i want to make each object appear after another with the help of `setTimout`.

Something like this : (onClick)

```js
const playScenes = () => {
    const cpScenes = [...scenes];
    for(let i; i < cpScenes.length;i++){
      const timer = setTimeout(() => {     
      showScene(cpScenes[i]);                 //Show the current scene
      }, cpScenes[i].duration);              //Time changes automatically
    }
    clearTimeout(timer);
  };
```

The way am thinking about this is that `setTimeout` should block execution of `for` loop and then run after specified time and then the loop continues..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither setTimeout nor setInterval block execution. Instead what you can do is  wrapping it a promise like:

```js
async function playscenes() {
   const cpScenes = [...scenes];
   for(let i; i < cpScenes.length;i++){
      await (new Promise( (resolve) =>
         const timer = setTimeout(() => {
             showScene(cpScenes[i]);
             clearTimeout(timer);
             resolve();
         }, cpScenes[i].duration);
    })
}
```

Basically what this does, is for every single loop, the program will wait for the `new Promise` to resolve, which that happens when the timer has run out.
If you don't understand asynchronous code (async/await) and promises work, I'd highly recommend that you do your research first.
Although this code should not run inside an a React component since i assume that you change the state every time the setTimeout is triggered.
What you could do is:

```js
imports ...
async function playscenes(showScene){...}
let scenesPlaying = false;
export function YourComponent(...){
  ...
  if(!scenesPlaying) {
     playscenes(showScene);
     scenesPlaying = true;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you the first part is what i wanted, and am not changing state am using refs.

Comment: One more thing please, how can i implement a stop button that gives me the scene and index where i stoped. Am still not confortable/confident using async/await. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Marwane,  
`let stop = false;
yourButton.addEventListener("click", () => stop = !stop);
for(let i; i < cpScenes.length;i++){
      while(stop) await (new Promise( (resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 200)); //Basically a sleep function
      await (new Promise( ....
` but I am not sure that it'll work 100% of the times. Inside the loop, while-loop will check every 200ms if the for-loop should stop running.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see how it is related to `react`, anyway, you can use `recursion` instead of `for-loop` to make it work

```
function playScenes(scenes) {
  if (scenes.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  const [scene, ...rest] = scenes;
  setTimeout(() => {
    showScene(scene);
    playScenes(rest);
  }, scene.duration);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for this trick, but i do need index for other calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple `for` loop based solution:

```
function newComputerMessage() {
    let total = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < cpScenes.length; i++) {
        total += cpScenes[i].duration;
        setTimeout(() => showScene(cpScenes[i]), total);
    }
}
```

In case you want to see the working, here's a working example snippet with dummy values:

```js
let cpScenes = [5000, 5000, 3000, 4000]

function test() {
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < cpScenes.length; i++) {
    total += cpScenes[i];
    setTimeout(() => showScene('test'), total);
  }
}

function showScene(num) {
  console.log(num);
}

test()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't match my situation